# Miss-understanding or Miss-use of JavaScript's SetTimeout function

Tags: javascript

I was trying to make a function execute 4 times a second, however I know this won't be 100% precise, because it doesn't take the execution time of the function into consideration, however I managed to have a completely different result than expected.

CODE:

```
var ClassObject = {
    myInteger: 0,
    running: false,
    paint: function() {
        this.myInteger++;
        console.log(this.myInteger);
        if(this.running) {
            setTimeout(this.paint(), 250); // 250ms wait
        }
    },
    start: function() {
        this.running = true;
        this.paint();
    },
    stop:  function() {
        this.running = false;
    }
}

ClassObject.start();
```

However, the result was something rediculous, the loop was running so fast my computer nearly crashed, and so much garbage was being created I couldn't escape hard-killing the process once it reached 80% CPU usage and almost 6GB of RAM.  Over about 2 seconds of execution the console was printing values of over 13k. Shouldn't that be sitting around 8?

Not exactly sure what I did wrong.

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3Lq9t1by/ (**Warning: May freeze your browser!**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking `paint` with the `()` instead of passing a reference to it into the *setTimeout*. You'll probably also need to bind it or something as you're using `this`, which will be lost when the *setTimeout* invokes it

```
function () {
    this.myInteger++;
    console.log(this.myInteger);
    if(this.running) {
        setTimeout(this.paint.bind(this), 250); // 250ms wait
    }
}
```

Please note however that this will create a new instance of the function each time, it may be more efficient to define another function inside paint which actually does the loop as you can bind it just the once

```
function () {
    var looper = function () {
        this.myInteger++;
        console.log(this.myInteger);
        if(this.running) {
            setTimeout(looper, 250);
        }
    }.bind(this);
    looper();
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate (or provide a link) about creating a new instance of a function? I guess that would understand the 6GB RAM usage from my original issue, but coming from Java I don't understand it at all. Are you suggesting something like this? `paint: function() { var foo = function() {} };`

Comment: @Christian.tucker it's the `.bind` that creates a new instance of a function. Because of the way _setTimeout_ works the older instances should be _GC'd_, but why create something new every time when you can re-use an old one

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just don't understand how a function can have its own instance. Coming from a Java background, a function (or method) is a set in stone set of instructions. You can execute this set of instructions in another thread, however you cannot create an additional instance of the instruction set that creates garbage.  Thanks for all of the helpful information though. I guess the transition from Java/C# to JS is going to be a little more tricky then I thought.

Comment: @Christian.tucker In _JavaScript_ functions are _first class_. In _JavaScript_ functions are _Objects_ `(function () {}) instanceof Object; // true`. _JavaScript_ is a prototypical language, not a classical one (it's the only mainstream prototypical language). There isn't really such a thing as a _"Class"_ in _JavaScript_, just _Objects_ and _inheritance_.

Comment: @Christian.tucker _"I just don't understand how a function can have its own instance."_ Consider `function foo() {return function bar() {};}`. What is the result of `foo() === foo();` ?